# ASP Update panel breaks jQuery star rating system

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I've added an `updatePanel` to my `ListView`. When the page first loads, it displays my rating system fine (here is the [krajee-star rating library](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating) that I'm using):

[image]

However, when the page does a partial-postback, it causes the control to appear like this:

[image]

Here is the code snippet:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemType="Country" SelectMethod="ListView1_GetData">
            <ItemTemplate>
             ...
            <input id="starRating" value="<%# Item.AverageRating %>" type="number" class="rating" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" readonly="true" data-size="xs">
             ...
        </ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What are my options? I did have a look at [triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers), but I think these only work with ASP controls. Ideally, I would like to keep the updatePanel.

I also tried to use `pageLoad()` but this also didn't solve the issue (it actually wipes out 'score' for the rating completely):

```
function pageLoad() {
  $(function () {
    $("div.star-rating").rating('create', { showClear: false, size: "xs", readonly: true });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the outputted HTML, I noticed that on partial-page load the rating-system was not rendering, but instead it was showing the `<input ...` tag, being the reason why it was displaying it like shown above.

I decided to look at the correct, star-rating markup, where I was able to understand how the star-system works and was able to configure some javascript code to run:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
  if (args.get_isPartialLoad())
  {
    $(function () {
      $('input[type="number"]').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();            
        var width = value * 20;
        var elem = "<div class='star-rating rating-xs rating-disabled'><div class='clear-rating' title='Clear'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'></i></div><div class='rating-container rating-gly-star' data-content=''><div class='rating-stars' data-content='' style='width: " + width +"%;'></div><input id='starRating' value='" + value + "' type='number' class='rating form-control hide' min='0' max='5' step='0.5' readonly='true' data-size='xs'></div><div class='caption'><span class='label label-default'>" + value + " Stars</span></div></div>"
        $(this).replaceWith(elem);
      })
    });
  }
};
```

This method will only run on partial load, which is when the problem arises. I loop through all the elements and grab the unrendered input. I then calculate the width, which is the amount of 'star' to show and I then insert the correctly, ready to ouput markup, replacing the old one unrendered one.

This has solved my issue, not pretty, but it has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the server side function to which the UpdatePanel is POSTing you could register a custom script that will be executed after the AJAX callback:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, 
    this.GetType(), 
    "wire_rating_control", 
    "$('div.star-rating').rating('create', { showClear: false, size: 'xs', readonly: true });", 
    true
);
```